# Difficulty using threads with Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, swingworker

```
package combatframe;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import static java.lang.Math.PI;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class CombatFrame extends JFrame
{
    String[] Ships = {"Battleship", "Cruiser", "Frigate"};
    JComboBox attackCombo = new JComboBox(Ships);
    JComboBox targetCombo = new JComboBox(Ships);
    JButton calculate = new JButton();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel outPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel shipPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea outText = new JTextArea("Results: ", 11, 30);
    JTextArea attackStats = new JTextArea("Attacker stats.", 10,10);
    JTextArea targetStats = new JTextArea("Target stats.", 10,10);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        CombatFrame combatFrame = new CombatFrame();
    }

    public CombatFrame()
    {
        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setTitle("OTG Combat Simulator");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        EventListener c1 = new EventListener();
        EventListener c2 = new EventListener();
        EventListener calc = new EventListener();

        calculate.setText("Calculate!");

        Border b1 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Result");
        outPanel.setBorder(b1);        
        Border b2 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Ship Classes");
        shipPanel.setBorder(b2);

        mainPanel.add(shipPanel);
        mainPanel.add(outPanel);
        shipPanel.add(attackStats);
        shipPanel.add(attackCombo);
        shipPanel.add(targetCombo);
        shipPanel.add(targetStats);
        outPanel.add(calculate);

        outPanel.add(outText);

        attackCombo.addActionListener(c1);
        attackCombo.setSelectedItem("Battleship");
        targetCombo.addActionListener(c2);
        targetCombo.setSelectedItem("Battleship");

        calculate.addActionListener(calc);

        this.add(mainPanel);
        this.setVisible(true);

    } 

    public double hitProbability(double factor)
    {
        double hitCount = (double)(Math.random() * 1.001 * factor );
        return hitCount;
    }

    public double Combat(double[] turnArray)
    {
        double rRange = turnArray[0];
        double rAngular = turnArray[1];
        double rRadius = turnArray[2];
        double damage = turnArray[3];

        double appliedDamage = 0;

        int[] attHit = 
        {
            0, 0, 0
        };

        int[] strikes =
        {
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        };

        double[] damageMod =
        {
            0,0.4,0.75,1.0,1.25
        };

        double roll1, roll2, roll3;

        roll1 = hitProbability(rRadius);
        roll2 = hitProbability(rAngular);
        roll3 = hitProbability(rRange);

        if (roll1 <=1)
            attHit[0]++;
        if (roll2 <=1)
            attHit[1]++;
        if (roll3 <=1)
            attHit[2]++;

        switch (attHit[0]+attHit[1]+attHit[2])
        {
            case 3:
                double wrecker = Math.random();
                if (wrecker >= 0.95 - Math.random())
                    strikes[4]++;
                else
                    strikes[3]++;
                break;
            case 2:
                strikes[2]++;
                break;
            case 1:
                strikes[1]++;
                break;
            case 0:
                strikes[0]++;
                break;
        }

        for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
        {
        appliedDamage += strikes[x]*Damage*
                (Math.random()+Math.random())*damageMod[x];
        }


        return appliedDamage;
    }

    private class EventListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getSource()== attackCombo)
            {
                switch ((String)attackCombo.getSelectedItem())
                {
                    case "Battleship":
                        Attacker attackBS = new Attacker(50000.0, 400.0, 0.01, 45000.0, 400.0,
                                300.0, 10.0, 10000.0, 250.0);
                        break;
                    case "Cruiser":
                        Attacker attackCr = new Attacker(25000.0, 125.0, 0.23, 22500.0, 150.0, 
                                600.0, 5.0, 5000.0, 75.0);
                        break;
                    case "Frigate":
                        Attacker attackFr = new Attacker(2500.0, 40.0, 0.365, 1000.0, 39.0, 
                                900.0, 2.0, 1200.0, 25.0);
                        break;

                }
                attackStats.setText("Optimal: " + Attacker.Optimal 
                        + "\n Weapon Sig: " +Attacker.Attack_Signature 
                        + "\n Tracking: " + Attacker.Tracking
                        + "\n Range: " + Attacker.Range
                        + "\n Ship Sig: " + Attacker.Target_Signature
                        + "\n Velocity: " + Attacker.Orbital
                        + "\n Cycle Time" + Attacker.Period
                        + "\n Health: " + Attacker.Health
                        + "\n Damage: " + Attacker.Damage);
                }

            if (e.getSource()==targetCombo)
            {
                switch ((String)targetCombo.getSelectedItem())
                {
                    case "Battleship":
                        Target targetBS = new Target(50000.0, 400.0, 0.01, 45000.0, 400.0,
                                300.0, 10.0, 10000.0, 250.0);
                        break;
                    case "Cruiser":
                        Target targetCr = new Target(25000.0, 125.0, 0.23, 22500.0, 150.0, 
                                600.0, 5.0, 5000.0, 75.0);
                        break;
                    case "Frigate":
                        Target targetFr = new Target(2500.0, 40.0, 0.365, 1000.0, 39.0, 
                                900.0, 2.0, 1200.0, 25.0);
                        break;
                }
                targetStats.setText("Optimal: " + Target.Optimal 
                    + "\n Weapon Sig: " + Target.Attack_Signature 
                    + "\n Tracking: " + Target.Tracking
                    + "\n Range: " + Target.Range
                    + "\n Ship Sig: " + Target.Target_Signature
                    + "\n Velocity: " + Target.Orbital
                    + "\n Cycle Time" + Target.Period
                    + "\n Health: " + Target.Health
                    + "\n Damage: " + Target.Damage);

            }

        if (e.getSource()==calculate)
        {

                double[] attackArray =
                {//RRange,RAngular,RRadius,Attacker.Damage
                    0,0,0,0
                };

                double[] targetArray =
                {//RRange,RAngular,RRadius,Target.Damage
                    0,0,0,0
                };

                double attackDamage = 0, targetDamage = 0;

                for (int i=1; i<1000; i++)
                {
                    if ((i+1)%Attacker.Period==0)
                    {
                        double rRange = Attacker.Optimal/Target.Range;
                        double rAngular = 
                            ((Math.sin(PI/4)*(Target.Orbital/Target.Range))
                            /Attacker.Tracking);
                        double rRadius = Attacker.Attack_Signature/
                                Target.Target_Signature;

                        attackArray[0] = rRange;
                        attackArray[1] = rAngular;
                        attackArray[2] = rRadius;
                        attackArray[3] = Attacker.Damage;

                        attackDamage += Combat(attackArray);
                        if (attackDamage >= Target.Health)
                        {
                            outText.setText("Attacker wins!");
                            break;
                        }
                    }


                    if (i%Target.Period==0)
                    {
                        double rRange = Target.Optimal/Attacker.Range;
                        double rAngular = 
                            ((Math.sin(PI/4)*(Attacker.Orbital/Attacker.Range))
                            /Target.Tracking);
                        double rRadius = Target.Attack_Signature/
                                Attacker.Target_Signature;

                        targetArray[0] = rRange;
                        targetArray[1] = rAngular;
                        targetArray[2] = rRadius;
                        targetArray[3] = Target.Damage;

                        targetDamage += Combat(targetArray);

                        if (targetDamage >= Attacker.Health)
                        {
                            outText.setText("Target wins!");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to build a very simple combat simulation frame. It builds 2 combo-boxes and assigns stats based upon the selections therein.

User then hits the calculate button, and out pops the result into the Results field. That all works fine.

I'd like the GUI to append each 'turn' of combat into the Results textfield outText - and I think I could do that easily enough. I'd like it to do so with a slight delay on any turn there is combat - I'd use a Thread.sleep(10) in each if-statement to do with an active turn for each ship.

The only problem with all that is I can't work out how to hold the GUI on one thread - which updates when prompted by the combat calculations after the button is clicked - and the thread handling all the calculations with delays.

I know if I try and run both on the same thread, the GUI will simply freeze up, do all the calculations with applicable delays, then throw out the entire appended lump at once into the results field.

Can anyone offer me any pointers, advice or cyanide? Anything, anything to make the pain go away...

Suspect that SwingWorker would be a good idea, but still can't work out how to actually implement that within my code.

Clarification: My biggest concern is that I can't work out how to implement SwingWorker, or some similar multi-thread process, in order to run the GUI and background calculations in parallel.

Comment: Well probably you are just going to make a big loop that runs one turn on each iteration with a sleep at the end. You can do something like append the results to a JTextArea. You don't necessarily have to use SwingWorker for this if you are sleeping although SwingWorker is "better" for a variety of reasons. Either way you will have to update the GUI with `invokeLater`. Can you narrow your question down a little bit? It is so open ended I am personally not sure what to say beyond what I suggested and what I suggested seems fairly obvious.

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions, variables are in lowerCamelCase. Your code it hard to understand as it stands as it's hard to tell what is a variable and what is a class.

Comment: Also true what @BoristheSpider says. And specifically on SO your code gets color-coded based on this. Straying from naming conventions makes it more difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

I will just take a stab at this since I think I understand what you are trying to do. Maybe what you are looking for is to create a new runnable each time the button is clicked:

```
class Turn implements Runnable {

    private final Object source;
    private final String attackComboMove;
    private final String targetComboMove;

    public Turn(Object src, String acm, String tcm) {

        source = src;
        attackComboMove = acm;
        targetComboMove = tcm;

    }

    @Override public void run() {

        // may want to disable GUI buttons here

        if (source == attackCombo) {

            switch (attackComboMove) {
                // ...
                // ...
                // ...
            }

            append("attack combo results");

        } else if (source == targetCombo) {

            switch (targetComboMove) {
                // ...
                // ...
                // ...
            }

            append("target combo results");

        } else if (source == calculate) {

            // ...

            for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {

                // ...

                attackDamage += combat(attackArray);

                append("combat results: " + attackDamage + " total damage");

                if (attackDamage >= target.health) {
                    append("Attacker wins!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // and enable the buttons again when combat is over

    }

    private void append(String text) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                outTextArea.append("\n" + text);
            }
        });

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

It sounds like you just want a scrolling list of the attacks as they happen and that's what this will do for you. IMO it is the right way to do it and ultimately the simplest.

When the user clicks the button you do:

```
new Thread(new Turn(e.getSource(), (String)attackCombo.getSelectedItem(), (String)targetCombo.getSelectedItem())).start();
```

(Or make a variable for the new thread if you need to be able to end it early for some reason or alter parameters.)

This pattern can easily be adapted to SwingWorker if it is long-running, just extend SwingWorker and do the same thing but override `doInBackground()` instead of `run()`.

Otherwise if you are intending to make a real-time simulation and need a background thread you will need to make run/doInBackground be a while(running) loop and use flags and/or some kind of wait/notify scheme when you need to change parameters or calculate a turn.

Comment: I'm really sorry - or really slow - but I can't actually work out how to apply this to my own code. I knew I wasn't that good with Java yet, but I didn't realise I was that thick :'( Thankyou for trying, though.

Comment: @Panda You just insert all of the calculations you are doing in your actionPerformed in to run(). All this lets you do is safely Thread.sleep off the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: Edited my answer to try to make it more clear how this can be used.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Why not? Forgive my ignorance but I've never heard that. The Java API docs show an example of doing it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: From the [Javadoc for `Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) - _In most cases, the Runnable interface should be used if you are only planning to override the run() method and no other Thread methods_. More importantly, `Thread` behaves in very special ways as a class, so you cannot use `wait` and `notify` on an instance of `Thread`. If you extend `Thread` this is a horrible bug waiting to happen.

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend waiting and notifying on an instance of Thread anyway because generally the assumption is it will be garbage collected as soon as it's done. That is a bug waiting to happen regardless of how Thread is treated differently from other classes. Runnable also does not let you use interrupt (except in roundabout ways) and the like.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have updated my code example to reflect the advice but I still do not completely see the technical rationale for this. I would not advocate doing anything bizarre while extending Thread because I would find that dangerous but merely overriding run so you are able to both have a reference to the Thread and the underlying Runnable object seems harmless and straightforward.

Comment: Best resource I found on the subject is this: http://manikandanmv.wordpress.com/tag/extends-thread-vs-implements-runnable/ But what it says is more like "extending Thread means you can't do these things" than "don't extend Thread because there is a real problem".

Answer (score 0):

You could use javax.swing.Timer to schedule something to happen N milliseconds in the future.  Note that `10` in Java time usually means `10` milliseconds, which is a nearly imperceptible amount of time.  If you want to sleep or delay for a second, use 1000 milliseconds, 10 seconds = 10000 milliseconds, etc.  Example:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel _contentPane;
    private GameFrame _mainFrame;
    private JButton _jButton;
    private JTextArea _jTextArea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                GameFrame frame = new GameFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(640/2, 480/2);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public GameFrame()
    {
        _mainFrame = this;
        _contentPane = new JPanel();
        _mainFrame.setContentPane(_contentPane);
        _contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        _jTextArea = new JTextArea();
        _contentPane.add(_jTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        _jButton = new JButton("Go");
        _jButton.addActionListener(new GoButtonListener());
        _contentPane.add(_jButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    class GoButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            _jTextArea.append("Please wait...\n");
            Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new LaterListener());
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    class LaterListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            _jTextArea.append("Ten seconds later!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This certainly looks to be what I'm after. Work beckons at this point, but I'll get back to you tomorrow after I've had the opportunity to rewrite my code into this framework and see what happens. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Also, just spotted the layout code. Thanks! I was dreading trying to move anything from the positions I had it in, as it had all just fallen where I thought it should do neatly...